# HTML5 color datalist default

Tags: html, colors, datalist

I'm looking for a way to add an option "transparent" or "_none" when using html5 color w/datalist.

I know it only takes hex values, but as an example - I just need a way to default to nothing, otherwise it has to be set to value when the form submits.

```
<input type="color" list="colors" name="bgColor">
<datalist id="colors">
   <option value=" [ _none or transparent etc ] ">
   <option value="#FF0000">
   <option value="#FFFFFF">
   <option value="#0000FF">
</datalist>
```

Answer (score 0):

I realize the manual says "only takes hex values", but missing the ability to *unset* or *not set* a color? This just seems like a silly hurdle to leave in what is supposed to be a standard html5 tag.

```js
function func(val) {

  var bg = document.getElementById('bgColor');
  var sel = document.getElementById('bgColorSelector');

  sel.classList.remove("none");

  bg.value = val;
  if (bg.value == '_none') {
    sel.classList.add("none");
  }

  if (val == "_none") {
    sel.value = '_none';
  }

}


func('_none');
```

```css
#bgColorSelector.none::before {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 55px;
  height: 13px;
  margin: 4px 4px 4px 7px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #FFF 46%, red 50%, #FFF 53%);
}
```

```html
<h3>Hidden value</h3>
<input id="bgColor" name="bgColor" type="text" value="_none" />

<h3>Selector with clear button</h3>

<input id="bgColorSelector" type="color" list="colors" onchange="func(this.value);" value="_none">
<datalist id="colors">
  <option value="#FFFFFF">
  <option value="#FF0000">
  <option value="#00FF00">
  <option value="#0000FF">
</datalist>

<input name="button" type="button" onclick="func('_none')" value="Clear" />
```